# Did Star Destroyers have any creature comforts?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In [Aftermath: Life Debt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Life_Debt) it's mentioned that the Death Star has a bar, albeit a lousy one.

**Do *Imperial Star Destroyers* have any sort of entertainment/bars for crew members?**

Comment: None. Apart from the [sports and sexual recreation deck](https://youtu.be/e0EokeUaaN8?t=5m47s), obviously.

Comment: There were two questions here, one answered by the question itself. I've edited.

Comment: @Valorum Don't forget about the [circus and zoo](https://youtu.be/EfkNvOOiZ_8?t=19)

Comment: I recall *Vision of the Future* having a brief discussion of recreational facilities on a Star Destroyer (in the context of a prolonged mission with comm silence and no contact with other ships having put strain on them), but I don't have it available to look up the details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing official I've seen or quickly researched again just now offer any information on recreation/entertainment for ISD crew.

The Dorling-Kindersley cutaways are the best detail I can find, but no luck.

However, there are almost 40,000 crew on an ISD, and if they're running a 3(or more)-watch system, then a significant number of those will be off-duty.

We could use Earth-based navies as analogues - ships and submarines have multiple wardrooms and messes were crew can play boardgames, read, watch TV/movies and relax. The bigger ships can even have kiosk style shops to buy cigarettes, magazines, and snacks.

We do hear a conversation between two Stormtroopers in SW:ANH about some new hologram that's worth watching - this could be on a personal viewer in a bunkroom/quarters, or in a wardroom type arrangement with a bigger viewer, perhaps.

Other than that, there's some mention under [Death Star](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/DS-1_Orbital_Battle_Station) (from Legends, not Canon) in Wookieepedia regarding recreational facilities, but no references

> Facilities included parks, shops, and other amenities for the Human crew

Finally, there is this from the [Galactic Data Bank](http://www.galacticempiredatabank.com/ISD.html) regarding ISDs, which is admittedly even less canon than Wookieepedia:

> A civilian area, with shops, services, eating establishments and leisure centres are found as well. Crew quarters include bedroom, living area with communications nook, and a small toilet room. Unlike most Imperial warships, the ISD provides recreational facilities for off-duty personnel. These multiple facilities are fairly large.